# Jquery Hide and show based on index, way around?

Tags: jquery, indexing, toggle, show-hide

I'm trying to make a divs showing and hiding on click. 
Currently the Main div called `#MAIN (1)` should be the default one. So when I click out of the box the main div shows up again.

I've update the FIDDLE, I now should make the number 1 as a default once i click out the container
e.g.
http://jsfiddle.net/srg6g/480/

Comment: That jsfiddle has a very strange output.

Comment: I've update the FIDDLE, I now should make the number 1 as a default once i click out the container

Comment: @MetalFrog now should make more sense I think

Comment: @MetalFrog. "Connect the dots" game ;-)

Comment: @DD77 it's been improved, I guess, but I still don't understand what we're supposed to be looking at or doing with it. http://i.imgur.com/x6aBF.png

Comment: @MetalFrog the numbers are image originally in p:absolute. they showing different content (one left) and they hiding each other.
the number one should be the default one, showing when the other are not visible

Comment: @MetalFrog I've update again the fiddle. now should be fine I think

Comment: Is it only for me jsFiddle in Chrome throws; `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getSelection' of undefined`? ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've finally understood what you were after.

What you want is bind click event on the document so when the user clicks outside the "numbers", the #MAIN is showed again:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    // use :not() to avoid fading when #MAIN is the current
    $(".hotspot_bub:not(#MAIN)").fadeOut('slow');
    $("#MAIN").show();
});
```

And stop the propagation when clicking on the hotspots:

```
$("#MAIN").show();
$('a.a_hotspot').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // so the click handler on "html" is not executed
    // when clicking on a hotspot
    e.stopPropagation(); 

    $(".hotspot_bub").fadeOut('slow');
    $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/N7j8H/)**